# Moving decimal place to right in c

Tags: c, double, decimal

I'm new to C and when I run the code below, the value that is put out is 12098 instead of 12099.

I'm aware that working with decimals always involves a degree of inaccuracy, but is there a way to accurately move the decimal point to the right two places every time?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    float f = 120.99;

    i = f * 100;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: Try this `float i, f = 120.99f;`.

Comment: none in standard c++, you need a decimal type, like http://sourceforge.net/projects/stddecimal/

Comment: Use `ftoa()` and copy each number to a `char` buffer, skipping the decimal point character via `isdigit()`.

Comment: `i = f * 100 + 0.5f` will avoid problems in numbers such as `120.99`.  It rounds up or down to the nearest integer (but use `-0.5f` for negative values).

Comment: If you need exact precision, use integer types instead. For example, using floating point types when handling money (e.g. bank accounts) would be a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that float are represented internaly using [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). That is in base 2 and not in base 10. `0.25` will have an exact representation, but `0.1` has not, nor has `120.99`.

What really happens is that due to floating point inacuracy, the ieee-754 float closest to the decimal value `120.99` multiplied by `100` is slightly below `12099`, so it is *truncated* to `12098`. You compiler should have warned you that you had a *truncation from float to in* (mine did).

The only foolproof way to get what you expect is to add `0.5` to the float before the truncation to int :

```
i = (f * 100) + 0.5
```

But **beware** floating point are inherently inaccurate when processing decimal values.

Edit :

Of course for negative numbers, it should be `i = (f * 100) - 0.5` ...

Comment: Minor point: "IEEE-754" does specify both floating point binary and floating point decimal formats of which your answer relies on the far more popular binary ones.  Decimal formats were somewhat popular in the past and I suspect they will have a minor resurgence for exactly these kind of issues.

Comment: @chux : I cited the wikipedia page that gives more details for that reason among others. But if OP system were using decimal IEEE 754, it would not have found any issue :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `round` function

```
float f = 120.99;
int i = round( f * 100.0 );
```

Be aware however, that a `float` typically only has 6 or 7 digits of precision, so there's a maximum value where this will work. The smallest `float` value that won't convert properly is the number `131072.01`. If you multiply by 100 and round, the result will be `13107202`.

You can extend the range of your numbers by using `double` values, but even a `double` has limited range. (A `double` has 16 or 17 digits of precision.) For example, the following code will print `10000000000000098`

```
double d = 100000000000000.99;
uint64_t j = round( d * 100.0 );
printf( "%llu\n", j );
```

That's just an example, finding the smallest number is that exceeds the precision of a `double` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

Use fixed-point arithmetic on integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define abs(x) ((x)<0 ? -(x) : (x))

int main(void)
{
    int d = 12099;
    int i = d * 100;
    printf("%d.%02d\n", d/100, abs(d)%100);
    printf("%d.%02d\n", i/100, abs(i)%100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to continue operating on the number as a floating point number, then the answer is more or less **no**. There's various things you can do for **small** numbers, but as your numbers get larger, you'll have issues.

If you'd like to only print the number, then my recommendation would be to convert the number to a string, and then move the decimal point there. This can be slightly complicated depending on how you represent the number in the string (exponential and what not).

If you'd like this to work and you don't mind not using floating point, then I'd recommend researching any number of fixed decimal libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
float f = 120.99f
```

or

```
double f = 120.99
```

by default c store floating-point values as double so if you store them in float variable implicit casting is happened and it is bad ...
i think this works.

Comment: no casting happens when you store a `double` value in a `float` variable. What happens is an implicit conversion.

Comment: float is 32 value and double is 64 bit value and their storing algorithm is different so casting between them is dangerous. you can see [Wikipeadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for details.

Comment: please don't teach me floating-point numbers. I'm perfectly aware of the shortcomings of converting between FP numbers of different precision. I was referring to the incorrect wording in your answer (a "cast" is an explicit conversion by definition; hence an implicit conversion cannot be called a "cast".)